# Not able to insert data in SQLite using C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, embedded-resource

My problem is I am not able to insert data into SQLite using C#. However I am able to select the records and retrive it using dataset. The SQLite database file is included in the solution directory and Build Action property of SQlite file is set to "Embedded Resource" in Visual Studio 2008. C# code is as follows :

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MonitoringDB.s3db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;Synchronous=Off");
        SQLiteCommand cmdinsert = new SQLiteCommand("Insert into Parameters(Id,Day,Time,Parameter) values(1,1,1,15) ", con);
        con.Open();
        cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Is something wrong with my code ?

Comment: What errors or exceptions are you getting?

Comment: Is there any password in that file??

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code but I never tried it on SQlite set to Embedded Resource.

Comment: @Danilo: I didnt get any exception as such.

Comment: @nikhil : there is no password in that file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't insert because the database is embedded in your EXE file. and you can't change embedded resources. What you can do is consider copying the resource out to disk on start up, if it doesn't already exist and work on that copy.

Comment: then should I place my DB file in another folder?

Comment: Change the `Build Action` of the database file to `Content` and `Copy to output Directory` to `Copy if newer` this will copy your database to the output folder (where your compiled exe is) and you can work on that file (insert/select/delete).